# codeigniter ckeditor data not store in database

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, ckeditor

Im using ckeditor, without ckeditor textarea store data in database properly but after use ckediter data not store in database.
Here is my html code :

```
  <textarea class="hidden ckeditor" name="article_description" id="article_description"></textarea>
```

Here is my modal :

```
  $data = array(
      'title'=> $this->input->post('article_title'),
      'description'=> $this->input->post('article_description'),
  );

  $query = $this->db->insert('articles', $data);
```

Only title save in database but description field is empty.

Comment: What does var_dump($_POST); show ?

Comment: no i dont know sir actually i m new in development

Comment: Put "var_dump($_POST);"  in your script and tell us what that output

Comment: Replace this $this->input->post('article_description') with a ramdom string to see if that's work.

Comment: yes is that work , and store the string in dataabase

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87057/discussion-between-sofiene-djebali-and-vijay-arora).